# A RegEx to Match This

Tags: regex

I have a string that follows this pattern:

```
junk/FISH/junk/junk/NOTJUNK1-Z32/NOJUNK2/junk
```

The `junk` text represents unknown text that I am not interested in and do not want matched.

`FISH` and the all forward slashes represent *known text* that I do not want matched by the RegEx.

`NOTJUNK1` represents some unknown text that I **do** care about and want matched. The `-Z32` will occur after `NOTJUNK1`, as shown. I know there will be a `-Z` but I do not know the two digit number that follows. It might even be one digit. I want the one or two digit value returned as a match as well (but I do not want the `-Z`).

Finally, `NOTJUNK2` also represents some unknown text that I **do** care about and want returned.

I am using the RegEx in the .NET library.

So, using the example string above, I would like three matches, if possible:

```
NOTJUNK1
32
NOTJUNK2
```

The closest I came was this RegEx:
`(?<=FISH/.+/.+/).*?(?=-m[0-9]{1,2}/)?/`

It returns two matches (which is close, but not what I want):

```
NOTJUNK1-Z32/
NOJUNK2/
```

Comment: What about [`/FISH/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]*?)-Z(\d+)/([^/]+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2fFISH%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b%2f(%5b%5e%2f%5d*%3f)-Z(%5cd%2b)%2f(%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b)&i=junk%2fFISH%2fjunk%2fjunk%2fNOTJUNK1-Z32%2fNOJUNK2%2fjunk)? The 3 captured values are `NOTJUNK1`, `32` and `NOJUNK2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with 3 capturing groups:

```
/FISH(?:/[^/]*)*?/([^/]+)-Z(\d{1,2})/([^/]+)
```

- [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA9iJ2/1)
- [RegexStorm Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2FFISH(%3F%3A%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D*)*%3F%2F(%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B)-Z(%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)%2F(%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B)&i=junk%2FFISH%2Fjunk%2Fjunk%2FNOTJUNK1-Z32%2FNOJUNK2%2Fjunk)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **capturing groups** like this to match.

**Regex:** `(?:.*?\/){4}(.*)-Z(\d{1,2})\/(.*)\/`

**Explanation:**

- `(?:.*?\/){4}` matches the `unnecessary` data and four slashes.
- `(.*)` matches the `NOTJUNK1`.
- `-Z(\d{1,2})` matches `one` or `two` digits after `-Z`.
- `(.*)` matches the `NOJUNK2`

Use backreferencing numbers `\1` for `NOTJUNK1`, `\2` for `32`(i.e number after `-Z`), `\3` for `NOJUNK2`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP6zW5/2)**

Comment: Doesn't it need to ensure `/FISH/` is there in input?

Comment: @anubhava: As OP mentioned _FISH and the all forward slashes represent known text that I do not want matched by the RegEx._ So `FISH` is non essential. Only `/` slashes are essential. Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: I guess `/FISH/` is not needed in matched data but it still needs be present in input

Comment: @anubhava: Yes and I counted that in `{4}`.

Comment: @noob, better take my pattern and add description to it. Your regex is rather poor.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes FISH is required.

Comment: @TomBaxter: But `FISH` is not part of match right ?

Comment: @noob: Correct, FISH is not part of the match, but it is known text and it will be present.

Comment: @TomBaxter: Yea then no problemo. `FISH` won't be matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
/FISH/[^/]*/[^/]*/([^/]*)-Z(\d+)/([^/]+)
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uQ2fQ4/2)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string textMatch = "junk/FISH/junk/junk/NOTJUNK1-Z32/NOJUNK2/junk";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"/(?<req1>.*?)-Z(?<req2>.*?)/(?<req3>.*?)/", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
        MatchCollection mcKVPs = r.Matches(textMatch);
        var kvps = from Match m in mcKVPs
                   where mcKVPs != null
                   where mcKVPs.Count > 0
                   select new
                   {
                       val1 = m.Groups["req1"].Value,
                       val2 = m.Groups["req2"].Value,
                       val3 = m.Groups["req3"].Value
                   };
        var kvp = kvps.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `RightToLeft` won't give any edge to matching in this case. It is redundant.

Comment: if you don't put right to left it will start from left and match more '/' and out put of req1 = /FISH/junk/junk/NOTJUNK1

Comment: That is why you should start with `/FISH/`.